# convertir Java a C#, xamarin android

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Hola alguien podria ayudarme con este codigo, lo qu pasa es que estoy teniendo problemas en pasarlo a c#

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
   final int pos = position;
   viewHolder.tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getName());
   viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(stList.get(position).getEmailId());
   viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isSelected());
   viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));
```

Esta es la parte con la que mas tengo problemas, lo anterior ya lo resolvi

```
   viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        Student contact = (Student) cb.getTag();

        contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

        Toast.makeText(
                v.getContext(),
                "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                        + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Dónde reside la dificultad? ¿Qué errores te señala la IDE y/o compilador? No me queda claro cuál es la "traducción" que no puedes realizar.

Comment: hola en la parte que tengo problemas es   viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        Student contact = (Student) cb.getTag();.....lo demas ya lo resolvi

Comment: Podrías inidcar como lo has resulto en la respuesta así en el futuro otros pueden ver cómo lo resolviste.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar algo como esto:

```
{
    //...   
    viewHolder.chkSelected.Click += chkSelected_Click;
}

private void chkSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    Student contact = (Student) cb.Tag;

    //  Asumiendo que usas propiedades
    contact.Selected = cb.Checked;
    stList[pos].Selected = cb.Checked;

    Toast.MakeText(
                cb.Context,
                "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.Text + " is "
                        + cb.Checked, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que definir la siguiente clase:

```
public class JavaObject<T> : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public JavaObject(T obj)
    {
        Value = obj;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

En el caso de la primera parte harias algo así para el Tag.

```
view.Tag = new JavaObject<Student>(stList[position]);
```

Y en la última parte harías lo siguiente:

```
viewHolder.chkSelected.Click += (s,a) => 
{
    var checkbox = (CheckBox)s;
    var contact = ((JavaObject<Student>)checkbox.Tag).Value;

    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes "traducirlo" tal cual, porque lo que hace este trozo de código en java no tiene traducción directa en C#

```
viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //manejar el click
    }
}
```

Lo que está haciendo es crear una implementación al vuelo de la interfaz View.onClickListener, para asignársela a chkSelected.

En C# no puedes hacer eso, lo más normal sería que la vista (Activity, Fragment, Adapter, etc) que este utilizando ese widget implemente la interfaz.

Sería algo como esto:

```
MiAdapter : View.IOnClickListener
{
    public void OnClick()
    {
    //maneja el click
    }

    ...
    //cuando tengas que asignaler el listener:
    viewHolder.chkSelected.SetOnClickListener(this);

}
```

O directamente utilizar el evento click:

```
viewHolder.chkSelected.Click += (s,e)=>{//maneja el click};
```